# Pass Data from Angular6 Micro App to Mobile Application

Tags: android, ios, swift, angular, kotlin

I have an application in Android (Kotlin) and iOS (Swift 4) that opens a micro app in a WebView which I made using Angular6.

There is a button in my web app that enable users to sync a date to their respective calendar.

What is the best way to pass data from my web application to my native application?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you can try using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/). From inside the web app the users would select to sync the data then that will open the dynamic link which will bring them back into the native Android or iOS app. These dynamic links can store small amounts of data which you can read in once you've handled the deep link. See [this sample code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#handle_deep_links) for Android.